# Layout won't center without margin

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using ConstraintLayout to display a RecyclerView or a Image with TextView conditionally based on the data in the RecyclerView. The problem is that the Image and TextView won't center vertically even when I've properly put constraints on all 4 directions. I'm also using the packed chain style. Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    tools:context=".ShortlistFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/shortlistedProfilesRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/interestProgress"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mpb_progressStyle="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shortlistBgImageView"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:contentDescription="Star image"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/shortlistHelperText"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shortlistHelperText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some Text Here!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shortlistBgImageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In Android Studio Preview the image and text is totally centered as expected. But in an actual device its at the top (I'm texting Android 9). I need to give `layout_marginTop` to my ImageView to have it centered, but that is just a hacky way of doing things. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I dont know why, but I tested your code on my device. And it is perfectly working. Both image and text is in center!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually using this fragment inside a `NavHostFragment` which had its height set to wrap_content.